# get most awaiting mysql

Tags: mysql

my site is like imdb its a movie databse and user can add movies into there awaiting list...
i have 2 tables..one for movie details storing and another to store who make a movie to his awaiting list...

```
Movie table : ID,MOVIE NAME,PLOT,RELEASE_DATE,ACTORS
awaiting Table : F_ID(just unique ID),U_ID(user id),MOVIE_ID(same as first tables ID)
```

Now i need to get top 6 most awaiting movie which is going to release...

IF in awaiting table There is 10 same movie_id rows..i want to list that 'ID's movie details from first table(like that top 5 movies)..another thing is when fetching rows release date of the movie should be greater than today date..don't want to show if release date is less than Today's date..which means only need to show upcoming most awaiting movies..

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your question (and what have you tried to address said question that didn't work)?

Comment: Could you rewrite your question so that it is a bit more clear? Maybe make an example, it is really difficult to understand the question as it stands.

Comment: how can i mark that movie as my favorite when it is not yet release? :D (*this is slightly not related to your question*). It's like saying that *One of my favorite movies is the FutureMovie which will be released on June 2016* hehe

Comment: @John Woo nice question :D ..honestly its not for favorites its for most awaiting..to avoid more complex i used the word Favorites :)

Comment: `favorite` is different from `most awaited`, can i change the title? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use only joins, try something like this:

```
SELECT m.MOVIE_NAME, COUNT(*) as FavoriteCount
FROM Favorites f
INNER JOIN Movie m ON m.ID = f.MOVIE_ID 
WHERE m.RELEASE_DATE > CURDATE()
GROUP BY f.MOVIE_ID
ORDER BY FavoriteCount DESC LIMIT 6;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should get you started. Tweak as needed.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Movie,
(
SELECT count(*) as favVotes, movie_ID
FROM Favorites, Movie
WHERE U_ID = [usersID]
AND Favorites.movie_id = Movie.ID
AND RELEASE_DATE > Now()
GROUP BY Movie_ID, U_ID
) favs
WHERE favs.movie_id = Movie.ID
ORDER BY favVoted DESC
LIMIT 5
```